# Android RecycleView OnClick does not work for whole itemView

Tags: android

So the problem is the onClick only gets called for the imageButton and not the while itemView. Here is my ViewHolder Class

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    protected TextView title;
    protected TextView rank;
    protected ImageView image;
    protected ImageButton share;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title =  (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_title);
        rank = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rank_text);
        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_image);
        share = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_share);
        share.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("click", "clicked at" + getAdapterPosition());
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

Because I was using cardviews in my recycleview, I ended up changing my viewholder code to this

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    protected TextView title;
    protected TextView rank;
    protected ImageView image;
    protected ImageButton share;
    protected CardView cardView;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title =  (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_title);
        rank = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rank_text);
        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_image);
        share = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_share);
        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_card_view);
        share.setOnClickListener(this);
        cardView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("test", "test" + getAdapterPosition());
    }
}
```

And it works

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick

Comment: @Garrett Please follow above url

Answer (score 1):

Because I was using cardviews in my recycleview, I ended up changing my viewholder code to this

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    protected TextView title;
    protected TextView rank;
    protected ImageView image;
    protected ImageButton share;
    protected CardView cardView;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title =  (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_title);
        rank = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rank_text);
        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_image);
        share = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_share);
        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_card_view);
        share.setOnClickListener(this);
        cardView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("test", "test" + getAdapterPosition());
    }
}
```

`And it works

Answer (score 0):

You are using same click listener for both `itemView` and `share`

- separate view clicks properly

  ```
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
      if (view.equals(share) {
          // 'share' was tapped
      }
      else {
          // 'itemView' was tapped
      }
  }
  ```
- in your XML layout (and I am guessing it here :) change as follow (i.e. add `clickable` on right places)

  ```
  // this is your list cell (the item renderer)
  <RelativeLayout
      android:clickable="true"
      ...>
      <TextView 
          android:id="@+id/main_title"
          android:clickable="false"
          .../>
      <TextView 
          android:id="@+id/rank_text"
          android:clickable="false"
          .../>
      <ImageView 
          android:id="@+id/main_image"
          android:clickable="false"
          .../>
      <ImageButton 
          android:id="@+id/main_share"
          android:clickable="true"
          .../>
  </RelativeLayout>
  ```

If it does not work for some reason, please post your XML layout and any other code you can share.

Answer (score 0):

`RecyclerView` doesn't support `onClick` method over a whole **itemview**. If you want to implement `onClick`, you need to set `OnClickListener` on child views of **itemview**.

Meanwhile, `RecyclerView` only support `onTouch` method of `OnTouchListener` on **itemview**.

Comment: I am trying this on a similar issue that I am looking to solve.  I'd appreciate any thoughts or insights you may have.  Located here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783631/recyclerview-how-to-add-onclick-and-keep-onlongclick-working

Answer (score -1):

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    protected TextView title;
    protected TextView rank;
    protected ImageView image;
    protected ImageButton share;
    protected CardView cardView;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title =  (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_title);
        rank = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rank_text);
        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_image);
        share = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_share);
        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_card_view);
        itemView.share.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.cardView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("test", "test" + getAdapterPosition());
    }
}
```